# How to create an attendance table in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have a table like this (`user_id` is `int` and `visited_at` is `date`):

```
 user_id | visited_at
---------+------------
      2  | 2020-01-14
      1  | 2020-01-14
      2  | 2020-01-13
      1  | 2020-01-12
```

I want to create a table like this:

```
user_id | 2020-01-12 | 2020-01-13 | 2020-01-14| 
--------+------------+------------+------------
      1 |     Y      |            |     Y     | 
      2 |            |      Y     |     Y     |
```

Here is a dummy example code:

```
CREATE temporary TABLE tbl (
  user_id    int
, visited_at date
);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  ('2', '2020-01-14'),
  ('1', '2020-01-14'),
  ('2', '2020-01-13'),
  ('1', '2020-01-12');
```

I would like the columns to be the last 30 days (for example), but without having to type them all out. I don't know if that means I can't use `crosstab`. The actual presence/absence values can be anything (Y, TRUE, etc.)

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: "*but without having to type them all out*" - not possible. The columns of a query have to be known _before_ the query is executed. The only thing you could do: generate the SQL query dynamically, then print the generated SQL and run it (which is essentially what `crosstab()` does as well)

Answer (score 0):

Why you need 30 columns for each day? If you make addendance 3 months then you need to create about 90 columns. you can add new column **is_present**. Means that whether student was absent in that day or not.

```
USER_ID   |    VISITED_AT       |  IS_PRESENT |
-----------------------------------------------
    1     |   2020-01-11        |     Y       |    
    1     |   2020-01-12        |     Y       |  
    1     |   2020-01-13        |     N       |  
    2     |   2020-01-11        |     Y       |  
    3     |   2020-01-11        |     Y       |  
    1     |   2020-01-14        |     N       |  
    4     |   2020-01-11        |     Y       |  
    5     |   2020-01-11        |     N       |
```

Comment: I just want to see a table (# students x 30 days). It makes it easier to see streaks